# Why is Google Chrome running all these tasks when closed?

Tags: google-chrome, task

since this morning, I have like 20 tasks from Google Chrome using a lot of memory for nothing even when the software is completely closed.

Here is the screenshot of the Taskmanager : 
[image]

I try to delete them one by one but they pop up again systematically and I tried the command prompt to kill them all but SAME, they come again.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a chrome icon in your sys tray?  What is "ChromeUpdate.exe"?

Comment: No, nothing, and Internet Explorer (that I never use) is launching too by itself and running a 100,00K task too that pops up again each time I force end the task. Virus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you did not disable the option to keep background apps running.

It can be found in the settings(chrome://settings) at the bottom of the advanced settings.

The use of these services depends on the extensions you have installed.

Comment: Yes I did, I actually have this by default since the beginning and I checked again, it is still disabled.

Comment: @FrenchyNYC And you are 100% sure that you do not have any other, old chrome installs?

Comment: 100000% sure ! I actually can not end that ChromeUpdate.exe it says it is denied and Internet Explorer is starting to do the same. I think of a virus but I am not sure...

Comment: @FrenchyNYC You could run taskmanager as admin and try to kill them all..., for the rest i'd recommend rechecking the chrome settings about background tasks and updating as well as a anti-virus scan.